# How to get the DataContext of VisualParent?

Tags: c#, togglebutton

I've a `ToggleButton` with this structure:

```
private void ToggleButton_Checked(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     //store settings
}
```

I need to get the details of `VisualParent`, in particular the `DataContext`, how can I do this? Thanks.

*UPDATE*

The xaml structure is this:

```
<ToggleButton Focusable="False" Width="19" Height="19" IsChecked="{Binding Path = IsFavourite}" 
                  Checked="ToggleButton_Checked" Unchecked="ToggleButton_Unchecked">
```

Comment: Share the xaml structure if possible.

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as answer if it resolves your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
((sender as System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton).Parent as Grid).DataContext
```

Instead of grid you can have a different control. So replace that as per your xaml structure.

Comment: is possible get the Name property of the object returned by your code?

Comment: Yes. Are you looking for the name of the Grid i.e. parent ?
((sender as System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton).Parent as Grid).Name

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

Do you really need it? Looking at your XAML, you are not setting DataContext in your ToggleButton, so you should inherit its value from whichever parent that sets its value.

See: [DataContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext(v=vs.110).aspx).

> This dependency property inherits property values. If there are child elements without other values for DataContext established through local values or styles, then the property system will set the value to be the DataContext value of the nearest parent element with this value assigned.

Anyway, if you need it...

ORIGINAL:
*Any answer that assumes a given structure in your XAML is wrong.* You can always apply a template that changes the structure.

Having said so, you can use the [VisualTreeHelper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper(v=vs.110).aspx) class (GetParent method) to navigate the visual tree. And the first parameter, is a reference to the control that was checked.

So, off the top of my head, I guess you could do the following:

```
DependencyObject source = sender as DependencyObject;
if(null != source) {
    DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(source);
    FrameworkElement parentElement = parent as FrameworkElement;
    if(null != parentElement) {
        object context = parentElement.DataContext;
    }
}
```

You should factor this in a helper method:

```
public static FrameworkElement GetParentContext(FrameworkElement element) {
    object result = null;
    DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element);
    FrameworkElement parentElement = parent as FrameworkElement;
    if(null != parentElement) {
        result = parentElement.DataContext;
    }
    return result;        
}
```

Please consider that given that the XAML structure *might be different*, maybe you will need to walk up the tree until you find an element with a `DataContext` that is not `null`.